# Element wise comparison between 2d arrays by if condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 2D numpy arrays a and b with size of `200*200`
I want to element wise comparison of these two arrays with conditions:

if `a[x][y]` and `b[x][y]` is `0` print `0`

if any of `a[x][y]` and `b[x][y]` is `0` print `non-zero element`

if `a[x][y]` and `b[x][y]` is `non-zero` print `little element/ large element`

I've tried `np.all` but it compares with only one condition

I want something like this C code:

```
for(i=0;i<200;i++)

  for(j=0:j<200;j++)


     if( a[i][j]==0 and b[i][j]==0)
       ....
       ....
```

After comparison I want to print results to another 2D array.
How can I do it with python coding?

Answer (score 4):

depends on your application ofc but the nice thing with numpy would be that you dont have to loop (and therefore its much faster)

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
a = np.random.randint(0,3,size=(5,5))
b = np.random.randint(0,3,size=(5,5))
print(a)
print(b)


where_a_eq_zero = a==0
where_b_eq_zero = b==0


# conditino: a and b is zero
con1 = where_a_eq_zero & where_b_eq_zero
print(con1)

# conditino: a or b is zero
con2 = np.logical_or(where_a_eq_zero,where_b_eq_zero)
print(con2)

# conditino: none of both is a zero element
con3 = ~where_a_eq_zero & ~where_b_eq_zero
print(con3)
```

```py
# a
array([[2, 0, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])

# b
array([[0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 2, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 0, 1, 1]])

# conditino: a and b is zero
array([[False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])

# conditino: a or b is zero
array([[ True,  True, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False,  True]])

# conditino: none of both is a zero element
array([[False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False]])
```

now if you further want to use it (based on your comment) you can just use it like:

```py
# fill up the array with np.nan because zero could be a possible 
# outcome and we can not differentiate if we missed that item or we wrote a 
# zero to this position. Later we can check if all np.nan´s are gone.
skor = np.full(a.shape,np.nan)

skor[con2] = -np.abs(a[con2]-b[con2])

my_min = np.minimum(a,b)
my_max = np.maximum(a,b)
skor[con3] = my_min[con3]/my_max[con3]

skor[con1] = 0

assert not np.any(skor==np.nan)
```

```py
skor
>>> array([[-2. ,  0. ,  1. ,  1. , -2. ],
           [-1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  0.5,  1. ],
           [ 0.5,  1. , -2. , -2. ,  0.5],
           [ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5, -1. , -1. ],
           [-2. , -1. , -1. ,  1. , -1. ]])
```

Comment: I don't want to print conditions. I want to print scores to another array like this if a == 0 and b == 0:
        skor[i,j] = 0
    elif a or b == 0:
        skor[i,j] = -abs(a-b)
    elif a != 0  and b != 0:
        skor[i,j] = min(a,b) / max(a,b)

Comment: see my edit i hope that is what you are looking for

Comment: maybe one more thing... you have to watch out for the order because con1 and con2 can be satisfied at the same time. Therefore you have to first apply con2 and then con1 if that is the correct result (I just changed it in my code).

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools  

for x,y in itertools.product(range(a.shape[0]),range(a.shape[1])):
    if a[x,y] == 0 and b[x,y] == 0:
        print(0)
    elif a[x,y] or b[x,y] == 0:
        print('non-zero element')
    elif a[x,y] != 0  and b[x,y] != 0:
        print('little element')
```

iterools.product just provides way to do a nested loop in one line

Comment: If you want to print conditions o another array just assign score[x,y] in the if statements instead of printing

Answer (score 1):

You can also use numpy.vectorize:

```
def conditions(x, y):
    if (x == 0) & (y == 0):
        return 0
    elif (x != 0) & (y == 0):
        return x
    elif (x == 0) & (y!= 0):
        return y
    else:
        return x / y if x < y else y / x

v_conditions = np.vectorize(conditions)
c = v_conditions(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use same approach just like C code.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
      for j in range(len(a[i])):
        if a[i][j]==0 and b[i][j]==0
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to print conditions. I want to print scores to another array like this if a == 0 and b == 0: skor[i,j] = 0 elif a or b == 0: skor[i,j] = -abs(a-b) elif a != 0 and b != 0: skor[i,j] = min(a,b) / max(a,b)

You may want to add that comment to the question, especially as momentarily it says *print non-zero element*, without the negative sign.

I think `-abs(0-0)` may be zero enough already (though a negative one), so if differences are calculated at the beginning, one can simply correct the result where both players/teams have a non-zero score.

```
 import numpy
 a=numpy.random.randint(0,3,size=(5,5)) # stolen from @nahtanoj
 b=numpy.random.randint(0,3,size=(5,5))
 c=-abs(a-b).astype(float) # difference for starters
 abmin=numpy.minimum(a,b)
 abmax=numpy.maximum(a,b)
 recalc=abmin!=0           # where minimum is not zero, both players/teams scored some
 c[recalc]=abmin[recalc]/abmax[recalc]
 print(a)
 print(b)
 print(c)
```

Example output:

> ```
> [[0 2 0 1 1]
>  [2 1 2 2 0]
>  [0 0 2 1 2]
>  [2 1 2 0 1]
>  [2 1 0 2 2]]
> [[0 2 1 2 0]
>  [2 1 2 2 2]
>  [1 2 1 2 2]
>  [1 0 2 0 2]
>  [0 2 0 1 1]]
> [[-0.   1.  -1.   0.5 -1. ]
>  [ 1.   1.   1.   1.  -2. ]
>  [-1.  -2.   0.5  0.5  1. ]
>  [ 0.5 -1.   1.  -0.   0.5]
>  [-2.   0.5 -0.   0.5  0.5]]
> ```